# [Android]Cannot connect the xampp myphpadmin after port forwarding

Tags: android

I am trying to start the xampp server in my desktop and connect the myphpadmin from other machines.

My router(ac68u) port forwarding setting:

- Name: server
- Port Range: 8081
- Local IP: 192.168.1.70
- Local Port: 8081
- Protocol: TCP

And I set the httpd.conf in apache:

- Listen 182.168.1.70:8081
- Listen 8081

After setting these, I can access the myphpadmin in other machines such as my laptop computer's web browser using the public IP and port(links like 123.456.789.0:8081/phpmyadmin). But when I trying to connect the myphpadmin in my android studio app, it has this error:

> E/ERROR: Communications link failure.
>   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

I am also tried to set the `bind-address=0.0.0.0` in *my.ini* and added the "allow from all" inside the . but it doesn't work, how can I do to solve this problem?

My code here:

```java
public class DbConnect {
    String classs = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://123.456.789.0:8081/testdb";
    String username = "user1";
    String pw = "";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN(){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnUrl = "";
        try{
            Class.forName(classs);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,pw);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnUrl);
        }catch (SQLException se){
            Log.e("ERROR", se.getMessage());
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: is phpmyadmin accessible in android's browser?

Comment: @ArsalImam, My phone and the android studio emulator also can access the phpmyadmin